# VB 2010 create installer with database

Tags: sql, installation, windows-installer

Can you guys help me out with this one? I got a program created in VB 2010 and i wanted to create an installer or an msi that includes the database. I'm using SQL for the database. Thanks and i hope to hear from you guys soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would probably do is on application load, first check to see if the DB exists.  If it does use app.config to record this, if it doesn't then programatically create it.

Here is a link to guid you though doing this:  [Create DB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307283)

Good luck

Paul.